# NoMethodError in SubmittedQuizzes#index, why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

routes:

```
  resources :users do 
    resources :submitted_quizzes,   only: [:index, :create, :show] 
  end
```

submitted_quizzes/index.html.erb:

```
    <% @submitted_quizzes.each do |quiz| %>
            <ul>                    
                <li> <%= quiz.name %> <span><%= link_to 'Show', quiz %></span></li>
            </ul>           
    <% end %>
```

submitted_quizzes/show.html.erb:

```
<%= @submitted_quiz.name %>
```

SubmittedQuizzesController

```
def index
    @user = current_user
    @submitted_quizzes = @user.submitted_quizzes

    end

def show 
        @submitted_quiz = current_user.submitted_quizzes.find(params[:id])

    end
```

Why is this happening?

submitted_quiz.rb

```
class SubmittedQuiz < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :quiz

  has_many :submitted_answers, :dependent => :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :submitted_answers, :reject_if => -> (a) {a[:content].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

Comment: Give us the `User` model code plz.

Comment: The name of the controller needs to capture the resource name in the plural form. That is, you should rename your controller to `class SubmittedQuizzesController`, and rename the file that contains the controller to `submitted_quizzes_controller.rb`.

Comment: sorry, that was just a typo -- in my app it's correctly labelled as submittedquizzescontroller. I found that if I un-nest the `:submitted_quizzes` then my code works, but I would really like for it to be nested inside `users`. Any ideas?

Comment: nevermind, I figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

Just didn't read up on nested resources paths. The correct path should have been `user_submitted_quiz_path(@user, submitted_quiz)`.